# Who did Voldemort kill to create the horcruxes?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, horcrux

Is there any information on who Voldemort killed specifically to create his horcruxes?  I know he's killed tons of people, but in doing something as important to him as creating the horcruxes, I feel like it would be in his nature to kill certain people that had some sort of meaning to him.

Is there any information on any of the identities of those he killed specifically to create the horcruxes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What order were the horcruxes made in?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14802/what-order-were-the-horcruxes-made-in)

Comment: I personally don't think it's a dup. The questions are asking two different things. :)

Comment: @Slytherincess True, but the answer there clearly identifies who died for each creation. So this question is answered elsewhere on this site.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that answer until now.  In any case though, there's no way for people to know that this question is answered from the linked one... there are duplicate answers on SE all the time.  The two questions themselves are different.

Comment: @John - correct. However, as I was told previously) the official rule is that if the answer from Q1 answers Q2, then Q2 is considered a dupe even if the question was different.

Comment: Rule or not, if the answers cannot be found through normal search means, I would consider that a short-sighted guideline. I mean, I think I included Voldemort's victims in my answer of what order the Horcruxes were made in, but I only did that as an offhanded FYI. So if someone Googled "Who did Voldemort kill to make his Horcruxes?" they're probably not going to get the "What order were the Horcruxes created in" question in the search results. Just because something is a rule doesn't mean it's a shining example of unadulterated logic. :)

Comment: I found some relevant meta posts: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74080/close-as-duplicate-what-if-only-the-answer-is-a-duplicate and also one on gaming: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/951/should-different-questions-that-yield-similar-duplicate-answers-be-closed

Comment: By typing "Who was killed to create the horcruxes?" into the site's search box, the possible duplicate is the second result.  This one is the first result only because it almost exactly matches the search terms.

Comment: Well, that's good to know -- at least it comes up in a search. I still view them as two distinct questions. Many, *many* questions carry the same canon information in their answers. I've certainly not seen people up in arms about it. :)

Comment: But why would I look in the second result... it's not the same question.  Type the same thing in google, and notice this question shows up on the front page already.

Comment: @Slytherincess That's why we mark questions as duplicates instead of closing them. Posting a question that is a duplicate is **not** a bad thing, *especially* in a case like this where there is another question whose answer is good enough that it covers both questions. That way whoever searches for *either* question will have access to an answer that covers everything.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

> **Lady Bella:** Whose murders did Voldemort use to create each of the Horcruxes?
>   **J.K. Rowling:** The diary – Moaning Myrtle. The cup – Hepzibah Smith, the previous owner. The locket – a Muggle tramp. Nagini – Bertha Jorkins (Voldemort could use a wand once he regained a rudimentary body, as long as the victim was subdued). The diadem – an Albanian peasant. The ring – Tom Riddle Sr. 
>   [THE LEAKY CAULDRON](http://www.the-leaky-cauldron.org/2007/7/30/j-k-rowling-web-chat-transcript)

Comment: A Muggle tramp? That seems a little harsh.

Comment: @JackBNimble: In British English, "tramp" means a homeless person, comparable to American English "bum".

Comment: @ruakh Also, [Lady and the Tramp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lady_and_the_Tramp) should be recognizable to US English speakers

Comment: @Izkata: It's not that people here are unaware of this sense -- I don't think anyone uses it anymore, but it's found in older works -- but its dominant sense here is roughly "slut", and that's what we think of when we hear it. It's like how if you heard a woman described as "quick", you wouldn't interpret that as meaning she's alive, even if you're aware that it *can* mean that.

Comment: This is six Horcruxes. If the idea is to create the magical number seven and Harry is not a Horcrux, where is the seventh?

Comment: @doneal24 There are only six at this time period, I think. But if it WERE the snake, then maybe it would be either Bertha Jorkins or Frank . . . but there might be some murders unsaid.