# How old was Tom Riddle when he made each Horcrux, and who did he kill to make them?

Tags: harry-potter, horcrux

How old was Tom Riddle when he made each of his Horcruxes, and who did he kill to create each? I know about Myrtle, The Riddle family, Hepzibah, and Harry's parents, but who were the others?

Comment: As such, perhaps it is worth editing this to ask only about Voldemort’s age.

Comment: gorramit. I always try to search to make sure I'm not asking duplicat questions, and I never find anything, and there's always something I missed. Ah well, least I'll get the questions answered.

Comment: @Valorum Found a better dupe [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/14802/82909). The one answer mentions all the dates, Voldemort's age, and who he killed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Full disclosure, I am taking my answer from the [Harry Potter wiki entry on Horcruxes](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Horcrux)

Voldemort was born on the 31st of December, 1926.

1. The Diary. Made from the murder of Moaning Myrtle. Date created: 13 June 1943 or later. Lord Voldemort's age: 16 (or 17, going from the 'later' in the date given)
2. The ring. Made from the murder of Tom Riddle Senior. Date created: August 1943. Lord Voldemort's age: 16
3. Salazar Slytherin's Locket. Made from the murder of a Muggle tramp. Date created: 1946 or later, but before 1979. Lord Voldemort's age: between the ages of 20 to 53.
4. Helga Hufflepuff's Cup. Made from the murder of Hepzibah Smith ([who claimed to be descended from Helga Hufflepuff](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Hepzibah_Smith)).  Date created: 1946 or later. Lord Voldemort's age: 20.
5. Rowena Ravenclaw's Diadem. Made from the murder of [an Albanian peasant](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Albanian_peasant). Date created: 1946 or later. Lord Voldemort's age: 20.
6. Nagini. Made from the murder of Bertha Jorkins. Date created: Summer of 1994. Lord Voldemort's age: 68

Edit: Regarding Pseudo-Horcruxes Harry and Professor Quirrell. [These Pseudo-Horcruxes were not created intentionally using the Horcrux-making spell for the purpose of obtaining immortality](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Horcrux#cite_note-Harry_not_Horcrux-9), as is also [pointed out in this question on SciFi&Fi](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11530/how-did-harry-become-a-horcrux).

1. Pseudo-Horcrux Quirrell was created between 1990-1991. Lord Voldemort's age: 64 - 65.
2. Pseudo-Horcrux Harry was created on the 31st of October, 1981. Lord Voldemort's age: 55

Comment: ah. Perfecto. Thanks!