# How does the soul split when making multiple Horcruxes?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, horcrux, souls

My question is regarding the size of the torn soul portions - are all the portions equal size? If yes how could it be? The soul doesn't know how many times it's going to be split.

There are two ways;

1. **Halving** : So on the first split, the soul divides into equal halves. One half in the Horcux and other half in the body. When the soul is split again, the half in the body divides equally (into quarters of the whole soul). The process repeats seven times. By the seventh time, the soul in the body (as well as the final Horcux) would be extremely small.

   Problem: This would mean that the earlier Horcruxes are stronger than the later ones (because they have larger soul portions in them). However this doesn't seem to be the case - or is it?
2. **Equal splitting**: Voldemort made seven Horcruxes - if this theory is correct, each soul portion in the seven Horcruxes are of equal size.

   Problem: But this doesn't seem to be plausible because how does the soul know how many times i'ts going to be split?

Comment: Is the soul a physical quantity? Does size have any meaning when discussing souls?

Comment: The correct spelling is Voldemort not Voldermort, no r in the middle.

Comment: The whole concept of "if I die, my consciousness/spirit/being/whatever will survive in my horcrux(es)" (horcruces?) requires that there be some connection between the pieces of the soul. And the connection between Voldemort and the bit of Voldemort in Harry suggests the same. It would be *possible* for that connection to also "equalize" the amount of soul in each vessel, like water finding its level. That's pure speculation, though.

Comment: @Michael I think that there must be some concept of potency at least, otherwise Harry would be 50/50 - and would quite possibly a Dr Jekyll/Mr Hyde as a result

Comment: @marcellothearcane I'd like to see a chronological horcrux list with their relative "evilness", expecting to see that each one is more evil than the last. (each containing less "soul" and more "murder"). . .The locket was particularly horrible.

Comment: @Aww Geez ....And the first horcrux the diary - Worse than the locket eh  ?

Comment: @TheMadHatter Maybe I have it backwards? Earlier horcruxes would be more evil as they contain more of Voldemort?

Comment: @Aww_Geez I agree.. The Diary was the first, the Locket was likely the second. ...still that doesn't explain why Voldy is so evil (lol) because he has only a small portion in him

Comment: @TheMadHatter I guess that only shows we cannot tackle this question through that route.

Comment: @Aww_Geez that's a good point - diary had enough soul to seduce Ginny and take over her body - locket was powerful but didn't end up possessing anyone to the extent it did Ginny

Comment: @Aww_Geez https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14802/what-order-were-lord-voldemorts-horcruxes-made-in